# GTK# : What should the parameter of ListStore be ?

Tags: c#, pygtk, monodevelop, gtk#

I'm trying to create a ListStore in order to set it as completion-model in an entry field.

```
ListStore store = new ListStore(string);
```

Output : 
Error CS1526: Unexpected symbol `)', expecting`.' (CS1526) (exercise)

In PyGTK, it's done as :    store = gtk.ListStore(str)

I'm newbie to C#, but used Gtk with Python. Forgive me if that's a silly question :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ListStore` constructor takes the column types as arguments. You can use the [typeof](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58918ffs.aspx) operator to obtain a type instance from its name:

```
ListStore store = new ListStore(typeof(string));
```

Comment: Thank you, it solved the case easily, i think i'd better learn C# fully rather than trying to learn by writing apps :)

Comment: You probably already know that but you can pass multiple types to create a multi-column ListStore. Also, for anything that is not a base type (string, int , etc.) just pass typeof(object).